# Calculate AWS Comprehend Sentiment cost

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-comprehend

I'd like to programmatically estimate the cost to call the AWS Comprehend Sentiment API. I searched SO and the [AWS calculators](https://calculator.aws/#/addService) but couldn't find a way. Also, I'm sure the costs for the amount of text I'll be sending will be small but I really want to know.

Based on the pricing info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/pricing/) I wrote the code below. Is it correct?

```
text = ["What a horrible rainy day today", 
        "What a great day today", 
        "This is a neutral statement"]

numChars = sum(len(i) for i in text)

#Sentiment is measured in units of 100 characters, with a 3 unit (300 character) minimum charge per request.
numUnits = int(math.ceil(numChars / 100))

# Up to 10M units
if numUnits < 10000000:
    pricePerunit = 0.0001
    sentimentCost = numUnits * pricePerunit

# From 10M-50M units
elif numUnits >= 10000000 and numUnits <= 50000000:
    pricePerunit = 0.0001
    sentimentCost = 9999999 * pricePerunit

    pricePerunit = 0.00005
    sentimentCost = sentimentCost + ((numUnits - 10000000) * pricePerunit)

# Over 50M units.
elif numUnits > 50000000:
    pricePerunit = 0.0001
    sentimentCost = 9999999 * pricePerunit

    pricePerunit = 0.00005
    sentimentCost = sentimentCost + (40000000 * pricePerunit)

    pricePerunit = 0.000025
    sentimentCost = sentimentCost + ((numUnits - 49999999) * pricePerunit)

print("\nEstimated $ charges to call AWS Comprehend Sentiment are: %0.5f\n" % sentimentCost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this calculation is not correct. Specifically:

- you need to round up for units so use `math.ceil(numChars / 100)`
- the cost/unit is different for the first 10M, the next 40M, and anything beyond 50M, and you have mistakenly assumed that *all* units are charged at the marginal rate. Your code will calculate the cost of 10M+1 units as (10M+1) * 0.00005 when it should be 10M*0.0001 + 1*0.00005
- also, your code will crash with exactly 10000000 or 50000000 units

Comment: I made the 3 changes above.